# 3D slam problems

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Ros Hydro, also installed Ros fuerte.
now trying Slam:

```
          http://wiki.ros.org/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM
```

It seems that it needs the earlier ROS version to get rgbdslam installed. Since there is command problem starting from

```
      rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam
```

Or is there any new package application performing the same as the video in the website?
I would like to sketch the 3D map of a big room like the function showed in the website.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102971/3d-slam-problems/) by [Battery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7016/battery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Pay attention, this package use ROS diamondback (which is the version from years ago). Meanwhile, others ROS have appeared (electric, fuerte, groovy and now hydro). You cannot install a package for older version in new version (the retro compatibility is not existing in ROS).

However, if you really want to use this package, you can install multiple version of ROS on the same machine. I let you find in ROS tutorial, everything is explained (I would have like to put the link, but wiki.ros.org doesn't want to load right now...)

Have a good day,

Stéphane

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Battery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7016/battery/) on 2014-01-14**:
I installed also fuerte but it still could not use the command --rosdep-install.
It seems that ROS has removed that command.